# Assembly.LoadFrom() throw exception

Tags: c#, reflection

```
public Assembly LoadAssembly(string assemblyName) //@"D://MyAssembly.dll"

{
    m_assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyName);
    return m_assembly;
}
```

If I put "MyAssembly.dll" both in D: and its copy in "bin" directory, the method will excute successfully. However, I delete any one of them, it will throw exception. Message like below:

Could not load file or assembly 'MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I wanna load the assembly which exists in D:. why I need put its copy to "bin" directory at the same time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe MyAssembly.dll refers to some assembly that arent in the directory. Put all assemblies in the same directory.

Or you can handle AppDomain.CurrentDomain, AssemblyResolve event to load the needed assembly

```
private string asmBase ;
public void LoaddAssembly(string assemblyName)
{
    asmBase = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(assemblyName);

    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
    System.Reflection.Assembly asm = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(assemblyName));
}

private Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    //This handler is called only when the common language runtime tries to bind to the assembly and fails.

    //Retrieve the list of referenced assemblies in an array of AssemblyName.
    Assembly MyAssembly, objExecutingAssemblies;
    string strTempAssmbPath = "";
    objExecutingAssemblies = args.RequestingAssembly;
    AssemblyName[] arrReferencedAssmbNames = objExecutingAssemblies.GetReferencedAssemblies();

    //Loop through the array of referenced assembly names.
    foreach (AssemblyName strAssmbName in arrReferencedAssmbNames)
    {
        //Check for the assembly names that have raised the "AssemblyResolve" event.
        if (strAssmbName.FullName.Substring(0, strAssmbName.FullName.IndexOf(",")) == args.Name.Substring(0, args.Name.IndexOf(",")))
        {
            //Build the path of the assembly from where it has to be loaded.                
            strTempAssmbPath = asmBase + "\\" + args.Name.Substring(0, args.Name.IndexOf(",")) + ".dll";
            break;
        }

    }
    //Load the assembly from the specified path.                    
    MyAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(strTempAssmbPath);

    //Return the loaded assembly.
    return MyAssembly;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I got some mistake.
It's all right at above code , the exception appears here:

    AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("NewDomain", null, appDomainSetup);
    Loader=(Loader)domain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(@"C:\\Loader.dll","Loader.Loader");
    assembly=Loader.LoadAssembly(@"D://MyAssembly.dll");
The exception appares the last line. I'm loadding a .dll file in new AppDomain.

The assembly is loaded successfully in LoadAssembly method, but throw exception at caller.

Comment: I think the exception appears by reason of I transfered Assembly from a AppDomain to another AppDomain.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/70ad4fcd-531d-4494-a9bb-1684d8b3f3ec/

Comment: Thanks very much, I got reason of the case. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/06/16/57188.aspx

Comment: @DeveloperX: +1, but what if at the resolve event the load is fail again? I think you should remove the `AssemblyResolve` handler first and then try to load the assembly again: `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve -= CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;  try { MyAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(strTempAssmbPath); catch { /*log exception*/ throw; }`

Answer (score 1):

To get any specific exceptions you could try this:

```
try
{
    return Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyName);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var reflection = ex as ReflectionTypeLoadException;

    if (reflection != null)
    {
        foreach (var exception in reflection.LoaderExceptions)
        {
            // log / inspect the message
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```